# Observing order state change

Tags: orders, event-observer, state

It seems there is no order state event by default, so how do you usually go about observing order state change?
There are two possibilities I see:
a) Overwrite the sales/order model to create your custom event for a state change
b) Observe the order save event and look at the state in there

Is one of these the way to go or is there a better option?

Edit:
Thanks for your answers so far.
The situation is a bit more complicated. I want to add information to the order depending on the current state. Now here is the problem:
In the save_before event I still have the old state and do not now the new state, because in the sales/order model the _beforeSave() method is as follows:

```
parent::_beforeSave();
$this->_checkState();
//...
```

So the event is processed in `parent::_beforeSave();` BUT the order state is actually changed afterwards in `$this->_checkState();` (this is the automatic change, e.g. if you create an invoice, the state is moved to processing if no shipment is there, yet)

I cannot use the save_after event either, since I want to save sth. at the order and it would probably break everything to call a save in the save_after event.

Any ideas? My only idea now is to replicate the `$this->_checkState();` behavior in my save_before observer to find out what the state will finally be...

Answer (score 11):

I would strongly advise against overwriting sales/order model because of two reasons:

1. It is always better to use events instead of rewrites.
2. Besides the general advice to use events instead of rewrites, it is particularly not a good idea to overwrite such a central and important Magento class. The possibility for a conflict with another extension is too high.

I do not have any idea for a better solution - I think it would be absolutely okay to observe the `sales_order_save_after` event and check if the state has been changed.

Comment: I updated my question - any idea for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to save the old sate from the original data in the `sales_order_save_before` event and check againts this in the `sales_order_save_after` or `before`, depending what you want to do.

Comment: I think you do not need to hook into the _before event in order to save the old state. You can use `getOrigData()` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8184430/719023

Comment: I'm sure they are set new after the save, because if not, you can't be sure, whether something changed at the next `save()`, but I don't find a place where this happens

Comment: I updated my question - any idea for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find overriding the `setState` method in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` easier and better:

```
protected function _setState($state, $status = false, $comment = '',
            $isCustomerNotified = null, $shouldProtectState = false)
    {
        // dispatch an event before we attempt to do anything
        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_status_before', array('order' => $this, 'state' => $state, 'status' => $status, 'comment' => $comment, 'isCustomerNotified' => $isCustomerNotified, 'shouldProtectState' => $shouldProtectState));

        parent::_setState($state,$status,$comment,$isCustomerNotified,$shouldProtectState);

        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_status_after', array('order' => $this, 'state' => $state, 'status' => $status, 'comment' => $comment, 'isCustomerNotified' => $isCustomerNotified, 'shouldProtectState' => $shouldProtectState));

        return $this;
    }
```