# How to generate Coupon rule dynamically using observer/model method?

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, coupon

How can i generate coupon rule dynamically using observer method?

I have created below function, it works if we create controller action and run. But not working with observer.

```
function createCoupon($customer_id, $discount,$days,$type)
{
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

    $customerGroupIds = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
    $websitesId = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->getAllIds();

    $customer_name = $customer->getName();
    $couponCode = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(9);

    $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
    $model->setName('Discount for ' . $customer_name);
    $model->setDescription('Discount for ' . $customer_name);
    $model->setFromDate(date('Y-m-d'));
    $model->setToDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$days.' days')));
    $model->setCouponType(2);
    $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
    $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
    $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
    $model->setCustomerGroupIds($customerGroupIds);
    $model->setIsActive(1);
    $model->setConditionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:32:\"salesrule/rule_condition_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
    $model->setActionsSerialized('a:6:{s:4:\"type\";s:40:\"salesrule/rule_condition_product_combine\";s:9:\"attribute\";N;s:8:\"operator\";N;s:5:\"value\";s:1:\"1\";s:18:\"is_value_processed\";N;s:10:\"aggregator\";s:3:\"all\";}');
    $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
    $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
    $model->setProductIds('');
    $model->setSortOrder(1);
    $model->setSimpleAction($type);//$model->setSimpleAction('by_fixed');
    $model->setDiscountAmount($discount);
    $model->setDiscountStep(0);
    $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
    $model->setTimesUsed(0);
    $model->setIsRss(0);
    $model->setWebsiteIds($websitesId);

    try {
        $model->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Can anyone have idea, why these happens?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error? Maybe the observer does not fire...

Comment: No.. observer fires but no coupon generates.

Comment: It is showing error like Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in  www\magento1702\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 3645' in  www\magento1702\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 245

Comment: huh?...I've never seen this error before. What event are you 'observing'?

Comment: I have created sales_order_status_after event as per http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1216/observing-order-state-change/1218#1218 post and using it.

Comment: Maybe your issue is somehow similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108986/file-was-not-uploaded-magento-error-even-file-is-uploaded-to-particular-folder. The example is for product events, but you can check if it's a similar issue. Maybe posting your observer might help.

Comment: I found the issue, it was because of  sales_order_status_after , now i have used  sales_order_save_commit_after, and there i can get order status as complete.. so it's working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer of above question.

Created event of sales_order_status_after

```
<events>
        <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <modulename>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mycompany_Offer_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>sales_order_save_commit_after</method>
                </modulename> 
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after> 
    </events>
```

Added Method sales_order_save_commit_after in observer:

```
<?php
```

class Mycompany_Offer_Model_Observer
{

```
    public function sales_order_save_commit_after(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {               


        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE){
            $orderTotal = $order->getBaseSubTotal();
            $customerId = 0;
            if($customerId = $order->getCustomerId())
            { 
                $customer_id = $customer->getId();
            }  
            $discountAmount = 10;
            $duration = 30;  
            $discountIn = 'by_fixed'; 
            Mage::getModel('offer/offer')->createCoupon($customer_id, $discountAmount, $duration, $discountIn); 

        } 
    }
```

}

Added above function createCoupon in model file:

```
class Mycompany_Offer_Model_Offer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

        /**
         * Function to create coupon dynamically
         *
         * @param int $customer_id
         * @param int $discount
         * @param int $days
         * @param text $type
         * @return nothing
         */
        public function createCoupon($customer_id, $discount,$days,$type)
        {
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);

            $customerGroupIds = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
            $websitesId = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->getAllIds();

            $customer_name = $customer->getName();
            $couponCode = Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(9);

            $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
            $model->setName('Discount for ' . $customer_name);
            $model->setDescription('Discount for ' . $customer_name);
            $model->setFromDate(date('Y-m-d'));
            $model->setToDate(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$days.' days'))); 
            $model->setCouponType(2);
            $model->setCouponCode($couponCode);
            $model->setUsesPerCoupon(1);
            $model->setUsesPerCustomer(1);
            $model->setCustomerGroupIds($customerGroupIds);
            $model->setIsActive(1);
            $model->setConditionsSerialized('');
            $model->setActionsSerialized('');
            $model->setStopRulesProcessing(0);
            $model->setIsAdvanced(1);
            $model->setProductIds('');
            $model->setSortOrder(1);
            $model->setSimpleAction($type);//$model->setSimpleAction('by_fixed');
            $model->setDiscountAmount($discount);
            $model->setDiscountStep(0);
            $model->setSimpleFreeShipping(0);
            $model->setTimesUsed(0);
            $model->setIsRss(0);
            $model->setWebsiteIds($websitesId);

            try {
                $model->save();  
                return $model->getData();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                print_r($e->getMessage());exit;
                Mage::log($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
}


Mage::getModel('offer/offer')->createCoupon($customer_id, $discountAmount, $duration, $discountIn);
```

As per above syntax we have to pass parameters like 'customer id', 'discount amount', 'duration' (in days), and 'discountIn'( like 'by_percent' or 'by_fixed')